# Best way to import a spreadsheet using long numbers onto MySQL using phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, excel, csv, phpmyadmin

I have recently been collecting data for my company to create a MySQL database. In doing this using PHP it can be used to view, add, edit and delete using a webpage interface.

I have currently created a prototype that allows me to import this data by converting a .XLS or XLSX sheet into a .CSV format that is then imported through PHPMyAdmin. Only recently I have found a snag with using this method. In my spreadsheet I have a few columns that represent barcodes, these barcodes vary in size, some going over 15 digits long. Excel has a limit to what it will represent and unfortunately displays the following:

[image]

This can obviously be changed by formatting the excel column to number, text etc.. however when saved as a CSV format it becomes impossible to change as every time you close the document it reverts back to it's original state.

When viewing the CSV file in Notepad++, the barcode will show fine although when I import the file into PHPMyAdmin, the barcode will show in the same way as the CSV.

So my question splits into two parts:

1. What is the best format to import my spreadsheet on?
2. How do I resolve this annoying format.

Comment: its only excels display that makes it look like that exporting to csv with that field as a "text" will result in the entire number being output into the csv which you can then import correctly. saving the file as .CSV will lose any column format you make since csv is a plain text file it stores no column formatting information as you set in excel. you must save in .xls(x) etc for that

Comment: I have tried using a 'OpenDocument Spreadsheet' format to get around this. This method keeps the format when importing but as my file is large, MySQL times out.

Comment: Don't import through phpmyadmin you use odf or xls to store the master then export it out as a csv (the raw csv opened in notepad will have the correct numbers in it!) and write a simple php import script

Comment: @Dave I'll give that a go. Do you know any useful links to tutorials to speed things up? Thanks

Comment: only thing you need with php is fgetcsv() then loop through it to import nice and simple like 4 lines of code will do it

Comment: I've come accross fgetcsv() in the past when I done an export. It's true that it works but I'm trying to keep off CSV as it will not accept the long number. Do you know any methods that would work with XLS or XLSX (obviously taking out the formatting apart from barcode).

Comment: csv will work fine with the long number its only a text field as if you'd created it in notepad. any field can be any length you like. I use it for numbers 4-5 times the length you've got and have no issues.  If you want to stick with xls xlsx though you can always use phpexcel to open and read the cells

Answer (score 1):

I'd say your data in the spreadsheet is stored incorrectly; it should be treated as text rather than a number. Likewise in the database. That will handle your question #2 and prevent this from becoming a problem in your database. It's not really a numeric representation (for instance a count of anything); it's a string of identifying characters that all happen to be digits. That seems to me like it should be represented as a string column type such as CHAR or VARCHAR.

I believe you said that the CSV looks fine (as in 5028252188661), so if you set the MySQL table to expect a string rather than a numeric type you should see the correct value represented after you import as well.

Comment: @Issac Your right in that data should be stored as text. I have edited a test sheet and stored the data as text. This now allows me use values longer than 15 digits in the field. With regards to the XLS to CSV conversion the field still produces 5.03E+12. Sorry for the late reply.